# Как скопировать часть изображения из bitmap'а в Texture2D?

Tags: c#, xna

Мне необходимо скопировать часть изображения из bitmap'a в Texture2D. Как скопировать именно часть изображения из Bitmap'a мне известно, однако как сконвертировать это в Texture2D?

Comment: А вы знаете, как скопировать _всё_ изображение?

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Я знаю, что необходимо использовать метод Bitmap.Clone, однако в том, как превратить это в удобоваримый для Texture2D вид я не знаю. Собственно, в этом и вопрос. Видимо, неправильно сформулировал, сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, должна подойти адаптация [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870399/276994):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

GraphicsDevice device = ...;
Bitmap bitmap = ...;

Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(device, w, h, 1, TextureUsage.None, SurfaceFormat.Color);

BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(startx, starty, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
try
{
    int bpp = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat);
    if (bpp != 32)
        thrpw new ArgumentException("ARGB image expected");
    int bufferSize = w * h * (bpp / 8);

    //create data buffer 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

    // copy bitmap data into buffer
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        Marshal.Copy(
            data.Scan0 + y * data.Stride,
            bytes,
            y * w, w);

    // copy our buffer to the texture
    tex.SetData(bytes);
}
finally
{
    // unlock the bitmap data
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

Тут `w`, `h` — размеры вашего куска, `startx`, `starty` — начальная `x`- и `y`-позиция вашего куска.

Обратите внимание, что [следующий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7394185/276994) утверждает, что надо ещё развернуть BGRA в RGBA.

---

Обновление: вот [этот ответ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/6442) подсказывает, что `SurfaceFormat.Color` соответствует формату ARGB. Это значит, что картинка с 24 bpp не подойдёт.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53074/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------bitmap--te).